# How to use AWS Batch to increase computation speed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I've made a docker container containing an R script which applies a random forest model to a data sample. This data sample is only 0.1% of the total data.
When running the same script on my local PC it takes 90 seconds.

I was hoping to prove that I could run this faster on AWS batch then I could scale up the process.

However, I've tried running both Fargate and ECS AWS batch jobs and the job seems to take 5 minutes with fairly high vCPUs, memory.

Does anyone know how I can improve the speed of this process?
Am I using the right service to be performing this computation?